# Transformation of discrete data to reduce Skew

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, skewness, kurtosis

In a dataset I have running through on kaggle's tabular playground, some of the measurement columns that are missing values follow a gaussian distribution.

I want to fix these missing values by replacing them with mean/median/interpolated values from the distributions but most of them have large skews/kurtosis values that could be detrimental to the ML techniques I will use later on.
[image: Plotted barchart of Kurtosis and Skew]
I am curious if the transformations I perform would have an adverse effect on how the generated values represent the missing values. Should I perform the replacement prior to the transformations or after, or does it not matter at all?

The missing data is as follows:
[image: Missing values matrix]
Each of the measurement attributes are normally distributed but some show signs of skewedness which I want to fix for the LDA classifier I will use.

Comment: Your question is cryptic: where are the missing values?  How do these plots show distributions?  If data are assumed to follow Gaussian distributions, why would skewness or excess kurtosis be relevant, since they must be zero for any Gaussian distribution?

Comment: my mistake, some of them are gaussian in nature, but some are also skewed where i suspect the LDA classifier I am using to predict failure attribute (failure rate) will be adversely affected. I am just wondering if imputation of missing values matters before or after the transformation of the skewed distributions or not.